# Do I need to fix confusing dependencies asap?

Tags: clojure, dependencies, leiningen

At some point, I've noticed that, according to `lein deps :tree`, dependencies in my project have turned into complete mess:

```
# counting lines that tell us about confusing dependencies
$ lein deps :tree 2>&1 >/dev/null | wc -l
     975
```

At the same time, the project is working fine now. Should I fix those conflicts ASAP, or leave them as is?

UPD:

Below is part of `lein deps :tree` output that I consider to be a confilct:

```
Possibly confusing dependencies found:
[hiccup-bridge "1.0.1"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
 overrides
[lein-create-template "0.1.2"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]

Consider using these exclusions:
[lein-create-template "0.1.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]
```

Comment: Conflicts? Which conflicts?

Comment: @MarcusMüller updated

Answer (score 3):

It's better to keep your dependencies clean, before buggy code occurs. From experience, bugs caused by dependency issues can be difficult to debug. Often it is not clear the buggy behavior is due to a bad dependency.

With that said, you're probably better off fixing your dependencies sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thank you. In your project(s), do you always keep your dependencies in conflict-free state?

Comment: I definitely try to! It's an easy thing to overlook or forget about, but once your dependencies are cleaned up, it's easier to keep them that way.